# Черный экран при захвате изображения с помощью анкулуа в эмуляторе нокс на 9 Андроиде (64 бит)

Tags: android, эмулятор

может кто подскажет,на эмуляторе нокс на 9 дроиде(64 бит) при захвате изображения с помощью ankulua вместо скриншота области экрана выдает черный скриншот,т.е анкулуа просто не может захватить экран,может какая то служба Нокса блокирует захват?пробовал захват изображения как через рут так и через медиа проекцию